# Machine learning analysis of differences

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

I'm very new to machine learning, and have a problem I'm trying to solve but don't know where to get started.

I've got a set of feature vectors that are "matched pairs," so

```
D={(x1,y1), (x2,y2), ..., (xn,yn)}
```

where each xi and yi are vectors of some length. xi and yi have the same length, but different pairs of xi and yi may have different lengths.

I want to have some algorithm learn the difference of x's and y's, such that, if I have another vector, I want to predict whether it's more like x's or more like y's.

Can someone point me in the right direction that I might try? I'm not sure what types of algorithms or methods I should be looking into, so even just the names of appropriate algorithms or methods would be great.

Comment: This seems a little unusual. Can you provide a simple example?

Comment: An example would be a study of genetic mutations. So x's and y's are genetic sequences, where y is a mutation of x. For example: x1=ACCTGG, and y1=GGCTGG, so the "AC" in x1 mutates to become "GG" in y1. In this example, I would be trying to find if there is some pattern in the mutation so that I can determine if a new sequence is likely to be x (unmutated) or y (mutated).

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not ML.  In your case, if you have a lot of $x$'s and $y$'s, then simply determine the correlation matrix for all pairwise combinations of all of your $x$'s and $y$'s.  Then look at the values and statistical significance of each correlation coefficient.  Your question really is asking if a given $y$ is associated more strongly with a given $x$.

Comment: Correlation testing is one valid approach, but it's certainly not the only one. This is a pretty open-ended problem.

Comment: @LEP: I'm not sure if I understand, I'm asking if I have a new vector that I don't know whether belongs to X or Y, then I'm trying to determine whether it's more likely to belong to X or belong to Y? I'm not trying to ask if a given y is associated more strongly with a given x.

Comment: Ok, then how about replacing each base with 1,2,3,4 and then determine the Euclidean distance, d(x,y), between the two vectors?  The same vectors will give you a distance of zero.  You can also weight the distance and reward with a 1 if the vectors are the same and near zero if very different by using: exp(-d(x,y)).  This called a radial basis function, RBF.  Why are you not using a pairwise alignment for two DNA sequences?